# Static fields and methods

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: where do static fields live within the memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142192/java-where-do-static-fields-live-within-the-memory)

Java uses the heap to save objects and instance variables and the stack for storing methods and local variable. I want to know where static feilds and methods are stored.

static fields --

static methods --

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question itself contains an error: methods themselves aren't stored anywhere that you have access to; there is a special "method space" where loaded code goes. Static fields are stored inside class definitions, which are stored in a special heap area called "PermGen space"; static methods, like normal methods, aren't stored in normal Java storage.

Comment: What I heard is, if we call method B() inside method A(). method B() stored in top of the A() in the stack. is it false?

Comment: That is a true statement about the *local variables* used in `A()` and `B()`; it's not true about the methods themselves. When you call a method, space is set aside on the stack for its local variables; that way a method can call itself, and each call gets its own private set of local variables. This has nothing to do with where the methods (the code?) are themselves stored.