# 'static' value appears to reset after function call

Tags: c#

I found a lot of articles about statics ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static), [MSDN 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members), [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781993/how-exactly-do-static-fields-work-internally), and lot lot more), but I still can't understand why this code returns `-1`:

```
class Program
{
    static int value = 0;

    static int foo()
    {
        value = value - 7;
        return 1;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        value -= foo();
        Console.WriteLine(value);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Here's what the debugger shows after `foo()` has run, but before the result is subtracted from `value`:

[image: foo=1, value=-7]

But one step later, `value` is `-1`:

[image: value = -1]

I would expect `-8` because of the static field which is stored in memory once.

When I changed it to

```
var x = foo();
value -= x;
```

it shows `-8`

How does this work exactly?

Comment: `value -= foo();` -> `value=0-1;`

Comment: Your `value` is initialized to 0. In `foo()` you subtract 7 from it, so it becomes -7. Then you subtract 1 more from it at ` value -= foo();` because `foo()` returns 1. So you end up with `value == -8`.

Comment: @pappbence96 which is exactly what he expects, but isn't getting.

Comment: @TvanB Sorry, misinterpreted the question! Still early it seems

Comment: The best way to understand is to debug the program line by line.

Comment: FYI, this has nothing to do with static.

Comment: Debuged this already , when method ends,  value = -7, but step next it magically changed on "-1". Thas the problem which can't understand

Comment: `value -= foo()` is the same as `value = current value of value (0) - foo() which returns 1`, which is the same as `value = 0 - 1`.  `foo()` does decrement `value` but only *after* you've referenced it in the calculation that calls `foo()`. Bad explanations have made it difficult to understand, but that's it in a nutshell.

Comment: @Archer when value of `value` is currently 7?

Comment: @koviroli miss-typed.  Refresh the page

Comment: I see. Like it.

Comment: Such statement would be UB in C++ ...

Comment: Statements like `i += i++;` are inherently ambiguous in meaning. Some languages have legalese in place that makes such statements well-defined, other languages (infamously the C family) just say: "The order of operand evaluation is undefined." **It doesn't matter what category your language falls in, code that's ambiguous in this way should not be written as it's hard to understand.**

Comment: @DavidConrad there was a misspeliing at archer's comment, it's already fixed.

Comment: And why exactly is this question up voted so much, it's a debugging problem and has no value to future readers

Answer (score 133, accepted):

This problem is not about static; it's about how the subtraction works.

`value -= foo();` can be expanded to `value = value - foo()`

The compiler will explain it into four steps:

1. Load the value of `value` onto the stack.
2. Call the method `foo` and put the result onto the stack.
3. Do subtraction with these two values on the stack.
4. Set the result back to `value` field.

So the original value of `value` field is already loaded. Whatever you change `value` in the method `foo`, the result of the subtraction won't be affected.

If you change the order to `value = - foo() + value`, then the value of `value` field will be loaded after `foo` is called. The result is `-8`; that's what you are expected to get.

Thanks for Eliahu's comment.

Comment: If you change `value = foo() - value` to `value = -foo() + value;` in your last sentence you will get the 'expected' result `-8`

Comment: @EliahuAaron ...probably. The order of evaluation of operands [is unspecified/unsequenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112282/), so the compiler would be allowed to evaluate the two arguments in either order, or indeed in parallel. But your comment usefully emphasises that `-=` is a more complicated thing than may at first appear.

Comment: @NormanGray you remind me to search definition from specification, the link is c++ standard, and I find [one for c#](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/expressions.md#operators), it's from left to right.

Comment: Wait, does this mean that addition is **not** commutative?

Comment: @AlbertoSantini The addition part is. You don't get an analogue in Maths, since in an immutable world, the problem doesn't exist. It comes from mutability - depending on the order you do `value` and `foo()`, you get different results. The final addition, `a + b`, is commutative, but how you *get* `a` and `b` isn't.

Comment: @AlbertoSantini Because of [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)), it is not. `A + B` means _first_ evaluate `A` (might cause side effects), keep the result, _then_ evaluate `B` (side effects), finally add the results.

Comment: @AlbertoSantini  (Another thing: Some overloads of `+` may be non-commutative for another reason, for example without side effects `"Hello" + "world"` is different from `"world" + "Hello"`, but I guess you would not call string concatenation "addition" even if it uses the operator `+`. User-defined overloads of the `+` operator can do anything, for example `DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromHours(0.5)` is OK, but `TimeSpan.FromHours(0.5) + DateTime.Now` does not match any overload.)

Answer (score 62):

The statement

```
value -= foo(); // short for value = value - foo();
```

is equivalent to

```
var temp = value; // 0
var fooResult = foo(); // 1
value = temp - fooResult; // -1
```

That's why you are getting `-1`

Comment: @Bahrom: It seems to work like you claim, but why?

Comment: @EliahuAaron: Because the C# spec says so. And why does the C# spec say so? Because (a) having a deterministic order of evaluation and (b) a -= b behaving like a = a - b (while evaluating `a` only once) are both widely considered to be good ideas. Would you have specified it differently? If yes, how, and why?

Answer (score 33):

Just look at the generated CIL:

```
.method private hidebysig static int32  foo() cil managed
{
  // Code size       19 (0x13)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] int32 V_0)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldsfld     int32 Program::'value'
  IL_0006:  ldc.i4.7
  IL_0007:  sub
  IL_0008:  stsfld     int32 Program::'value'
  IL_000d:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_000e:  stloc.0
  IL_000f:  br.s       IL_0011
  IL_0011:  ldloc.0
  IL_0012:  ret
} // end of method Program::foo
```

- `IL_0001:` - Push the value of the static field on the stack. **s:[value(0)]**
- `IL_0006:` - Push `7` onto the stack. **s:[7, value(0)]**
- `IL_0007:` - Subtracts value2 (`7`) from value1 (`0`), returning a new value (-7).
- `IL_0008:` - Replaces the value of the static field with val *(value = -7)*.
- `IL_000d:` - Push `1` onto the stack. **s:[1, 7, value(-7)]**
- `IL_000e:` - Pop a value from stack into local variable 0. *(lv = 1)*
- `IL_0011:` - Load local variable 0 onto stack. **s:[lv(1), 7, value(-7)]**
- `IL_0012:` - Return *(lv(1))*

And the `Main` method:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       29 (0x1d)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldsfld     int32 Program::'value'
  IL_0006:  call       int32 Program::foo()
  IL_000b:  sub
  IL_000c:  stsfld     int32 Program::'value'
  IL_0011:  ldsfld     int32 Program::'value'
  IL_0016:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
  IL_001b:  nop
  IL_001c:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

- `IL_0001:` - pushes `value` onto stack (which is `0`)
- `IL_0006:` - calls `foo` (which will return `1`)
- `IL_000b:` - subtract values: `value2(1)` from `value1(0)` (`value(0) - value(1) = -1`).

So the result is `-1`.

Answer (score 17):

You can use menu *Debug* → *Windows* → *Disassembly* and check what goes on in the background:

I commented the most interesting parts.

```
    //static int value = 0;
    05750449  mov         ebp,esp
    0575044B  push        edi
    0575044C  push        esi
    0575044D  push        ebx
    0575044E  sub         esp,2Ch
    05750451  xor         edx,edx
    05750453  mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],edx
    05750456  mov         dword ptr [ebp-1Ch],edx
    05750459  cmp         dword ptr ds:[15E42D8h],0
    05750460  je          05750467
    05750462  call        55884370
    05750467  xor         edx,edx
    05750469  mov         dword ptr ds:[15E440Ch],edx  // STEP_A place 0 in ds register
 somewhere
    0575046F  nop
    05750470  lea         esp,[ebp-0Ch]
    05750473  pop         ebx
    05750474  pop         esi
    05750475  pop         edi
    05750476  pop         ebp
    05750477  ret

    //value -= foo();
    057504AB  mov         eax,dword ptr ds:[015E440Ch]   // STEP_B places (temp) to eax. eax now contains 0
    057504B0  mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],eax
    057504B3  call        05750038



    057504B8  mov         dword ptr [ebp-44h],eax
    057504BB  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-40h]
    057504BE  sub         eax,dword ptr [ebp-44h]   //STEP_C substract the return(-1) of call from the temp eax
    057504C1  mov         dword ptr ds:[015E440Ch],eax  // STEP_D moves eax (-1) value to our ds register to some memory location

    //Console.WriteLine(value);
    015E04C6  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[015E440Ch]  // Self explanatory; move our ds(-1) to ecx, and then print it out to the screen.
    015E04CC  call        54CE8CBC
```

So it is true that when writing `value -= foo()`, it generates code something like this:

```
value = 0; // In the beginning STEP_A

//... main
var temp = value; //STEP_B
temp -= foo(); // STEP_C
value = temp; // STEP_D
```

Answer (score 7):

I think it has something to do with how it subtracts `value` on the assembly level, and that causes some inconsistency in the program. I don't know if it has something to do with static or not. But from my intuition this is what happens:

Let's focus on `value -= foo()`

1. The old `value` get saved (pushed to the stack)
2. The `foo()` function returns `1`
3. Now, the `value` is `-7` due to `foo()` operation
4. HERE is the problem: The OLD `value` (which is the one that saved earlier, which is `0`) subtracted with `1` and the result assigned to the current `value`.

Comment: It's not just an accident - the C# specification specifically defines the order of execution in such a case - the compiler is not allowed to produce code that would output anything else than `-1`, unlike in C.

Answer (score 5):

```
value -= foo(); // value = value - foo();
```

`foo()` will return `1`.

`value` is initially `0`, so: `0 = 0 - 1`.

Now the `value` has `-1`.

So the issue is with return `1`.

Comment: This answer ignores the fact that calling `foo` changes `value`.

Comment: @Theraot: This answer is correct; the fact that `foo` changes `value` is irrelevant. Regardless of what values `foo` changes, the fact is that subtraction in C# proceeds from left-to-right.

Comment: @EricLippert that is true, however, it is still not good explaining it.

Comment: @Theraot i have explained only the core-concept, remaining upto you.