# Unable to load Object from another class Page Object Model

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I defined the Object in a Class Called "Page Objects Login page" when I call them in the TestCase class I'm unable to load the object to use it in the test case

I want to be able to select the variables on the TC class, but when I call the PO class, I'm unable to see them.

How I want to call it:
LoginOage.(here should display the defined objects?)

How I define the Object:
public class LoginPage{

```
    private IWebDriver driver;

    [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "#contentLogin > div:nth-child(1) > form:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > button:nth-child(1)")]
    [CacheLookup]
    public IWebElement HP_Accountbtn {get; set;}
```

How I want to call it:
LoginOage.HPAccountbtn

When I set Loginpsge.it doesn't display the objects. Is this the correct way to set up this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only access [static fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781993/how-exactly-do-static-fields-work-internally) without instantiating the class so my expectation is that you need to amend your code to look like:

```
LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage()
IWebElement myElement = loginPage.HP_Accountbtn
```

Another option is to make your button [static](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/163457/understanding-the-static-keyword/163465)

```
public static IWebElement HP_Accountbtn {get; set;}
```

this way you will be able to access it as:

```
IWebElement myElement = LoginPage.HP_Accountbtn
```

Actually the main idea of the [Page Object Model Design Pattern](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Design+Patterns+-+Page+Object+Model) is to provide [abstraction](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/csharp/csharp-abstraction) layer between test logic and the application under test [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) so I would rather recommend exposing a function which will allow to click the button

```
public class LoginPage {

    [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "#contentLogin > div:nth-child(1) > form:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > button:nth-child(1)")]
    [CacheLookup]
    private IWebElement HP_Accountbtn {get; set;}

    public void clickHPAccountBtn() {
        HP_Accountbtn.click();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, I managed to call the object with your solution. But Now i received this error when executing the Testcases: System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.